# moving cs cart to another directory without data

Tags: cs-cart

Firstly, I have made a sub directory for development and installed cs cart MVE in it.
I want to copy the current cs cart sub-directory and add it to the main domain folder without the testing dummy data I have added in the development phase.
How can I do that?

Secondly, if I have made new changes in the future on the development folder, how can I apply this change to the main domain folder?

Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

Note: a step-by-step guide will be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish those results. First of all, if you just want the demo data to be removed you can alter the database and do the following:

Alter the table and remove every single product, property, banner, etc. Though if you have this code setup you could just run it in one time. Though I do not recommend this as this is way more work than needed and this wont get rid of the images and such stored by the demo data.

You can also do the following:

Go to the products section, click the checkbox in the top left and after that click the gear icon in the top right and select: "Delete selection". Do this a few times and for everything needed (banners, payment methods, shipping methods, etc.) and you are all set.

Or you can do this (recommended):

You can do a store-import of your current store and then switch the directories around so you have no downtime. This is also the way I do my development. You can get the store-import addon for free in the cs-cart marketplace.

But if you were looking for a way just to copy a store without transferring any data you could think about what you want to copy. Basically every setting is stored in the database (so are this similar?). Furthermore every image path, etc. is stored in the database (so are these similar?). And so on. The best way I see how you can do this is by running a store import (this will give you the option to remove all the demo data before importing the new data, you could install a new version of cs-cart with no data, then it will delete all the current data you allready have.)

Hopefully my answer suffices, feel free to ask if you stumble across some problems.

Comment: Thank you for the big help :), i went over to check the store-import but it does not support multi-vendor edition.

Comment: if you move the main app to other directory you have to delete cs-cart cache from var => cache